# What is a "valid SharePoint user"?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-email

I am wanting to use AJAX / `SP.Utilities.EmailProperties` to send an email out to a group mailbox.

I have got the code to work to send emails to individuals, but am unable to send to a group mailbox. All advice states that the user must be a *valid SharePoint user*, but there is little to explain what this actually means.

How do I set up a group mailbox as a "valid user"? Our security environment is based on Active Directory, and I assume that AD is imported into SP. If this is the case, is there a flag that is set on the import that is used to ascertain if it is a true user or not?

How do I go about getting a group mailbox to be associated with a "valid user"?

Comment: Further confusion. In the people picker, I can select IDs that are associated with a group mailbox (but are not associated with any sharepoint group) . However, I cannot send to this "user" either. This user is defined as a group mailbox in MS Outlook...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the distribution group doesn't require authenticated senders.

You can review this in groups properties and unchecking "Require that all senders are authenticated".

Comment: I am not sending to a SharePoint group.

Comment: I am talking about the Group in AD. I am assuming it is a Security Group in AD which has a valid email address associated with it.

Comment: Ok... so where I can select a valid "group user" in a people picker field on the list, but am unable to send any email to that ID either... so is this the same issue?

Comment: I will follow up this line of thought with the security guys. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

I have been advised that the cause of our problem was that sharepoint and exchange exist in different domains, and thus the exchange user information was not accessible to SharePoint.

With the next SharePoint software rollout, the intention was to bring all this architecture into the one domain.